# Core-Data migration on background thread failing when running as a UIBackgroundTask

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios4, core-data-migration

My code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        @autoreleasepool {            
            // Now on a background thread

            // Setup background task
            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;

            void (^finishBackgroundTask)(void) = ^(void) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            };

            // Start background task
            bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:finishBackgroundTask];

            // The method below migrates a core data database and takes ages
            [MyClass migrateCoreDataStuff];

            finishBackgroundTask();
        }
    });
```

The error I get is `NSUnderlyingException = "Fatal error.  The database at /var/mobile/Applications/55B83D5F-CCF5-438E-BECA-B97DB5505541/Documents/Blah.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'";`

The migration error only occurs when the following are all true:
* migration is on a background thread
* migration is running as a UIBackgroundTask
* I'm running on the device, not a simulator

I'm running iOS 4.3.5, building for iOS 4.0.

Comment: Whoops...figured it out.   One should never call anthing in UIKit from any but the main thread.  In this case I am starting a background task (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]`) thereby messaging my UIApplication instance from the background thread.  Which is *bad*.

Comment: __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;       
void (^finishBackgroundTask)(void) = ^(void) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
};
bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:finishBackgroundTask];dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [MyClass migrateCoreDataStuff];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), finishBackgroundTask);
    }
});

Comment: That's unlikely to be the underlying problem. `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` is specifically marked as thread safe in the documentation. You might just be masking the real issue.

Comment: You're right, the above code actually doesn't work (I was a bit hasty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the contents of `migrateCoreDataStuff`, it's hard to see the exact problem. However, Core Data on non-main threads is a tricksy issue. Have a read of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html. You'll probably need, at a minimum, a separate managed object context for the new thread.

Comment: Yeah, that method is huge, I couldn't post it here, but essentially its that progressive migration from http://media.pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/code/ProgressiveMigration/AppDelegate.m (I use a separate context as you suggest, and while migrateCoreDataStuff is running, nothing else in the app could possibly be accessing the persistent store)

Comment: A brief look at the code indicates that you're sharing the managed object context? At least, there's exactly one place where it's created, and that reference is returned for every call in the future?